# Accessing element in a python numpy.matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I seem to be stuck with something seemlingy trivial: I need to access elements in a numpy.matrix. But the matrix doesn't behave as I expect:

```
>>> mymatrix
matrix([[0.02700243, 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        ]])
>>> type(mymatrix)
<class 'numpy.matrix'>
>>> mymatrix.shape
(1, 10000)
>>> mymatrix[0]
matrix([[0.02700243, 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        ]])
>>> mymatrix[0][0]
matrix([[0.02700243, 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        ]])
>>> mymatrix[0][0][0]
matrix([[0.02700243, 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
         0.        ]])
```

i.e. no matter whether I take the matrix itself, or the [0] element of the matrix or the [0][0] element of the [0][0][0], i always get the same object ... How is that possible?

Comment: A `np.matrix` is always 2d - that's the key way it differs from `np.ndarray`. Look at the shape of `mymatrix[0]`.

Comment: You need to use 2 dimensional indexing: `mymatrix[0,3]`

Answer (score 0):

According to [NumPy Manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html):

> A matrix is a specialized 2-D array that retains its 2-D nature
> through operations

And:

> It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear
> algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the
> future.

Maybe you could consider using a regular array instead. You can return your matrix as an array using:

```
mymatrix.A
mymatrix.A[0]
mymatrix.A[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to transpose your matrix to index the first element in a matrix with this shape.

Try:

```
mymatrix.T[0]
```